# Why is PHPStorm giving me a "a term expected" error on a SASS map?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

`$ sass -v
Sass 3.4.2 (Selective Steve)`

`PHPStorm 7.1.3`

Open a new .scss file and add:

`$objects: (vegetable: carrot, mineral: salt, animal: chicken);`

On each colon within the map PHPStorm gives me a red squiggly error stating "a term expected".

Comment: I'm thinking it's a phpstorm bug. If I configure the file watcher to compile even when syntax errors exist, it outputs what appears to be a valid and expected CSS file. Hrumph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is PHPStorm giving me a “a term expected” error on a SASS map?

Because this feature was introduced in **SASS v3.3 (released on 7th of March 2014)** .. and PhpStorm v7.1.3 (at the end February 2014) does not support that version.

Such support was added later and will be available in upcoming **PhpStorm v8**. You can **try latest public EAP build** if you wish so now: http://eap.jetbrains.com/phpstorm